# Testing grails plugin controllers by itself

Tags: grails-plugin, grails-controller, grails-2.0

I created a simple grails 2.0.1 plugin with a domain "User". Created scaffolding controllers and views. But when I do grails run-app and goto the user/list url, I get the error

No signature of method: packagename.User.list() is applicable for argument types: () values: [] Possible solutions: list(), list(java.util.Map), is(java.lang.Object), wait(), lock(), find()

But when I use the plugin within a grails app (without publishing,packing), it works fine.

Question is - I want to be able to test the grails plugin controller without an app. Im guessing im missing some configufaration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you don't have the Hibernate plugin installed. It's added to `BuildConfig.groovy` by default for applications, but not for plugins. You can install it with `grails install-plugin hibernate 2.0.1` and it will add it to `application.properties`, and this approach keeps it from being a dependency when users install your plugin.

You can also add it to `BuildConfig.groovy` but be sure to add `export = false` unless your plugin does actually require Hibernate to function. If it would work with any GORM implementation (e.g. Mongo) then it shouldn't be exported:

```
plugins {
    build(":tomcat:$grailsVersion",
          ":hibernate:$grailsVersion",
          ":release:1.0.1") {
        export = false
    }
}
```